# execute javascript function

Tags: javascript

Need help with the following JavaScript function.

when I isolate each as if they were separate functions 
(i.e. to remark out all but one at a time).
I do get the expected value alerted.

But when run as block of code only the first value is alerted.
Not able to see what I'm doing wrong

```
function stateChanged(){ 

    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;            

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){ 

        var product = document.getElementById ("product");
            for (var i = 0; i < product.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = product.childNodes[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                     //alert ("The " + i + ". child is a text node. Contents:\n" + child.data);
                    var customerProduct =  product.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                    alert(customerProduct);   
                }
                else {
                    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                        var product =  ("The " + i + ". child is an element node. Contents:\n" + child.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            }

         var model = document.getElementById ("model");
            for (var i = 0; i < model.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = model.childNodes[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                     //alert ("The " + i + ". child is a text node. Contents:\n" + child.data);
                    var productModel =  model.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                    alert(productModel);   
                }
                else {
                    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                        var model =  ("The " + i + ". child is an element node. Contents:\n" + child.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            }

         var serial = document.getElementById ("serial");
            for (var i = 0; i < serial.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = serial.childNodes[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                     //alert ("The " + i + ". child is a text node. Contents:\n" + child.data);
                    var productSerial =  serial.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                    alert(productSerial);   
                }
                else {
                    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                        var serial =  ("The " + i + ". child is an element node. Contents:\n" + child.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            }

         var computer = document.getElementById ("computer");
            for (var i = 0; i < computer.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = computer.childNodes[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                     //alert ("The " + i + ". child is a text node. Contents:\n" + child.data);
                    var computer =  computer.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                    alert(computer);   
                }
                else {
                    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                        var computer =  ("The " + i + ". child is an element node. Contents:\n" + child.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            } 

         var os = document.getElementById ("os");
            for (var i = 0; i < os.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = os.childNodes[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                     //alert ("The " + i + ". child is a text node. Contents:\n" + child.data);
                    var os =  os.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                    alert(os);   
                }
                else {
                    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                        var os =  ("The " + i + ". child is an element node. Contents:\n" + child.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            }
    } 
 }
```

appreciated.
ussteele

Comment: You do not understand JavaScript closures. See the [Jibbering JavaScript Closure Notes](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) and/or other SO questions. I have given you one for free :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a javascript closure work ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work)

Comment: Well I don't see the closure in this one. Could you enlighten us pst?

Comment: respondents.
Thank you for your help in direction.

Comment: Closures are good to know about anyway. But the problem at hand... I don't see the problem, perhaps there's a prob with the multiple var declaration of 'child'?